# Facebook Graph API Search posts in a language

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, posts

I want to obtain the results for this query filtered in spanish. Is it possible?

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Gasol&type=post

There must have been some changes in the lasts weeks because in December I got the results in spanish by default.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, quite a lot of details have changed recently. In November I found out that results are based on HTTP Accept-Language header, language settings of user(when using access token) and localisation of requesting machine.

There is also locale parameter for specifying language. It is not working for some time now, but there is an bug report on that, and it seems, they are going to fix that http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331184190290797.

UPDATE:
Bad news: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294623187324442. locale is not working by design.

UPDATE 2:
Facebook changed it's mind. Bug got fixed, locale parameter and Accept-Language header are working again.

Comment: Thank you very much Aleksandra!